# Finding the error in the script that runs a FIFO/LIFO calculation on a transactional history of an investment tracker

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, undefined-reference

**Introduction**

I have a spreadsheet and the idea of this spreadsheet is that any user can input his or her transaction history in the sheet "history" and based on this history, an overview is provided of a person's realized gains (=they have sold it in the past) and their unrealized gains (= never sold it). A script is run which then creates a report (sheet: Report) with the necessary data. A query table summarises this data in the summary of RG report sheet. Based on this summary, the position sheet is created, which shows all the current positions held by the user. The user can chose to run the script by going to the menu CoinAtlas>Build Report>LIFO or HIFO. Please see here the [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vjaHS89jGVjxp82wnWThgEdGa8MthyUKlE3pr19JqcI/edit?usp=sharing).

**What is FIFO and LIFO?**

These are accepted accounting methods to calculate realized gains. FIFO (=first in, first out) & LIFO (=last in, first out). An example of FIFO: You buy 2 stocks of company A for 10 dollars each at date Y. At date Y+1 you buy 2 more stocks of company A for 15 dollars each. You hold 4 stocks of company A. You decide to sell 3 stocks of company A for 20 dollars each. Profit is then calculated as (3 * 20-(2 * 10+1 * 15)) = 60 - 35 = 25 dollars. The same scenario LIFO would be: 60 - 40 = 20 dollars.

**Description of the problem**

When building a report, for whatever reason, the stock MSTR and the cryptocurrency THETA is ignored and not shown in the output sheet "Report". The script was written by an experienced programmer who unfortunately no longer responds to this issue. With my beginner's skills in javascript I cannot seem to find out why.

**The FIFO script calculation**

```
function createReport_LIFO () {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const inputSheet = ss.getSheetByName('History');
  const report = ss.getSheetByName('Report');
  const data = inputSheet.getRange(2, 1, inputSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 9).getValues();
  const filterd = data.filter(row => row[2] == 'Buy' || row[2] == 'Sell');
  const sorted = filterd.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[0] < b[0]) return 1
    if (a[0] > b[0]) return -1
    else return 0
  })

  //console.log(sorted);
  const securityObject = sorted.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (curr[1] in acc) {
      if (curr[2] in acc[curr[1]]) {
        acc[curr[1]][curr[2]].push(curr)
      } else {
        acc[curr[1]] = { ...acc[curr[1]], [curr[2]]: [curr] }
      }
    } else {
      acc[curr[1]] = { [curr[2]]: [curr] }
    }
    return acc
  }, {});

  console.log(JSON.stringify(securityObject));
  //console.log(securityObject);

  const objects = [];

  Object.keys(securityObject).forEach(ticker => {
    const tic = securityObject[ticker];
    let index = 0;

    try {
      tic.Sell.forEach(sell => {
        const [date, security, , quanity, total, , account, ] = sell;
        let totalBuy = 0;
        let remainder = quanity;

        do {
          let [, , , buyQuanity, , buyPrice] = tic.Buy[index];
          if (buyQuanity < remainder) {
            totalBuy += (buyQuanity * buyPrice);
            remainder -= buyQuanity;
            index++;
          } else {
            totalBuy += (remainder * buyPrice);
            securityObject[ticker].Buy[index][3] = (buyQuanity - remainder);
            buyQuanity -= remainder;
            remainder = 0;
            if (buyQuanity <= 0) {
              index++;
            }
          }
        } while (remainder > 0);

        objects.push({
          date,
          security,
          account,
          quanity,
          totalBuy,
          total,
          result: total - totalBuy
        })
      })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  })

  const convertToSheetsArray = [["Sell Date", "Security", "Account", "Quantity Sold", "Total Buy", "Total Sell", "Result"]]
  objects.forEach(obj => convertToSheetsArray.push(Object.values(obj)));
  report.getDataRange().clearContent();
  report.getRange(1, 1, convertToSheetsArray.length, 7).setValues(convertToSheetsArray);
}
```

Output of securityObject

```
Logging output too large. Truncating output. {"ETH":{"Buy":[["2021-10-26T22:00:00.000Z","ETH","Buy",0.087541,301.25,3441.2446739242187,"Bitvavo","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-07-11T22:00:00.000Z","ETH","Buy",1.19,2113.84,1776.3361344537818,"Bitvavo","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-07-09T22:00:00.000Z","ETH","Buy",0.109074,195.55,1792.8195536974897,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-07-09T22:00:00.000Z","ETH","Buy",0.0529245,94.95,1794.0651305161127,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-07-09T22:00:00.000Z","ETH","Buy",0.0443436,81.22,1831.6059138184542,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-07-09T22:00:00.000Z","ETH","Buy",0.31543836,576.66,1828.1226164122843,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-07-05T22:00:00.000Z","ETH","Buy",0.19039196,498.75,2619.595911508028,"Bitvavo","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-07-05T22:00:00.000Z","ETH","Buy",0.57131,1116.81,1954.823125798603,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-05-18T22:00:00.000Z","ETH","Buy",0.1036,250,2413.127413127413,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""]]},"MATIC":{"Sell":[["2021-10-21T22:00:00.000Z","MATIC","Sell",37.14,61.82,1.6645126548196014,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""]],"Buy":[["2021-05-18T22:00:00.000Z","MATIC","Buy",37.14,65,1.7501346257404415,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""]]},"XTZ":{"Buy":[["2021-10-21T22:00:00.000Z","XTZ","Buy",8.6,58.82,6.839534883720931,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-09-25T22:00:00.000Z","XTZ","Buy",35.17,200,5.686664771111743,"Bitvavo","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-09-11T22:00:00.000Z","XTZ","Buy",35.777,200,5.590183637532493,"Bitvavo","Cryptocurrency",""]]},"TFUEL":{"Sell":[["2021-10-20T22:00:00.000Z","TFUEL","Sell",754,182,0.2413793103448276,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""]],"Buy":[["2021-07-04T22:00:00.000Z","TFUEL","Buy",754,261,0.34615384615384615,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""]]},"THETA":{"Sell":[["2021-10-20T22:00:00.000Z","THETA","Sell",81.4,397.73,4.886117936117936,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""]],"Buy":[["2021-03-26T23:00:00.000Z","THETA","Buy",19.5,200.56,10.285128205128204,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-03-20T23:00:00.000Z","THETA","Buy",26,200,7.6923076923076925,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-03-19T23:00:00.000Z","THETA","Buy",35.9,249.81,6.95849582172702,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""]]},"ONE":{"Buy":[["2021-10-20T22:00:00.000Z","ONE","Buy",2768,579.73,0.2094400289017341,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-09-11T22:00:00.000Z","ONE","Buy",1241,200,0.16116035455278002,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""]]},"ALGO":{"Buy":[["2021-09-25T22:00:00.000Z","ALGO","Buy",145.18,200,1.3776002204160351,"Bitvavo","Cryptocurrency",""]]},"UPST":{"Buy":[["2021-08-09T22:00:00.000Z","UPST","Buy",2.8786672,336,116.7206824046906,"Trading212","Stock",""]]},"AXS":{"Buy":[["2021-08-08T22:00:00.000Z","AXS","Buy",3,106,35.333333333333336,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""]]},"safemars":{"Sell":[["2021-08-08T22:00:00.000Z","safemars","Sell",206130076,16,7.762089021885385e-8,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""]],"Buy":[["2021-04-19T22:00:00.000Z","safemars","Buy",206130076,200,9.70261127735673e-7,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""]]},"safemoon":{"Sell":[["2021-08-08T22:00:00.000Z","safemoon","Sell",55800000,90,0.0000016129032258064516,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""]],"Buy":[["2021-04-19T22:00:00.000Z","safemoon","Buy",55800000,300,0.000005376344086021505,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""]]},"FRA:C36":{"Sell":[["2021-07-13T22:00:00.000Z","FRA:C36","Sell",358,343.68,0.96,"Bitvavo","Stock",""]],"Buy":[["2021-03-18T23:00:00.000Z","FRA:C36","Buy",358,253.9,0.7092178770949721,"DeGiro","Stock",""]]},"BTC":{"Sell":[["2021-07-11T22:00:00.000Z","BTC","Sell",0.038237,1116.81,29207.57381593744,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-07-04T22:00:00.000Z","BTC","Sell",0.00537222,257,47838.69610700977,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-07-04T22:00:00.000Z","BTC","Sell",0.00543778,261,47997.528403135104,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-07-04T22:00:00.000Z","BTC","Sell",0.00533832,261,48891.78617992178,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-07-04T22:00:00.000Z","BTC","Sell",0.00550857,261,47380.71768172139,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-07-04T22:00:00.000Z","BTC","Sell",0.00008389000000000313,0,0,"Bitvavo","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-06-06T22:00:00.000Z","BTC","Sell",0.038276,1116.81,29177.81377364406,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-05-02T22:00:00.000Z","BTC","Sell",0.01032703,498.75,48295.58934175654,"Bitvavo","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-04-13T22:00:00.000Z","BTC","Sell",0.18413661999999997,9757,52987.83044893515,"Bitvavo","Cryptocurrency",""]],"Buy":[["2021-06-23T22:00:00.000Z","BTC","Buy",0.038276,1000,26126.03197826314,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-04-14T22:00:00.000Z","BTC","Buy",0.18428,9757,52946.60299544172,"Bitvavo","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-03-22T23:00:00.000Z","BTC","Buy",0.00094112,43.52,46242.77456647399,"Bitvavo","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-02-21T23:00:00.000Z","BTC","Buy",0.025382,1000,39397.99858167205,"Bitvavo","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-02-21T23:00:00.000Z","BTC","Buy",0.046151,1770.3,38358.86546337024,"Bitvavo","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-02-21T23:00:00.000Z","BTC","Buy",0.046339,2003,43224.929325190446,"Bitvavo","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-02-16T23:00:00.000Z","BTC","Buy",0.048543,2045.36,42135.0143172033,"Bitvavo","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-02-07T23:00:00.000Z","BTC","Buy",0.0027187,100,36782.28565123036,"Bitvavo","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-01-23T23:00:00.000Z","BTC","Buy",0.0077802,200,25706.2800442148,"Bitvavo","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-01-10T23:00:00.000Z","BTC","Buy",0.0019139,50,26124.66691049689,"Bitvavo","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-01-09T23:00:00.000Z","BTC","Buy",0.0043677,134,30679.7628042219,"Bitvavo","Cryptocurrency",""]]},"BAT":{"Sell":[["2021-07-09T22:00:00.000Z","BAT","Sell",168.5,81.22,0.4820178041543027,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""]],"Buy":[["2021-05-30T22:00:00.000Z","BAT","Buy",168.5,100,0.5934718100890207,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""]]},"BNB":{"Sell":[["2021-07-09T22:00:00.000Z","BNB","Sell",0.7359,195.55,265.7290392716402,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""]],"Buy":[["2021-05-18T22:00:00.000Z","BNB","Buy",0.7359,250,339.7200706617747,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""]]},"LINK":{"Sell":[["2021-07-09T22:00:00.000Z","LINK","Sell",6.2,94.95,15.314516129032258,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""]],"Buy":[["2021-07-04T22:00:00.000Z","LINK","Buy",6.2,261,42.096774193548384,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""]]},"XMR":{"Sell":[["2021-07-09T22:00:00.000Z","XMR","Sell",3.09982,681,219.69017555858085,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""]],"Buy":[["2021-05-24T22:00:00.000Z","XMR","Buy",1.51782,300,197.65189548167768,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-05-18T22:00:00.000Z","XMR","Buy",1.192,250,209.73154362416108,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-04-19T22:00:00.000Z","XMR","Buy",0.39,100,256.4102564102564,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""]]},"RUNE":{"Buy":[["2021-07-04T22:00:00.000Z","RUNE","Buy",17.2,261,15.174418604651164,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""]]},"SOL":{"Buy":[["2021-07-04T22:00:00.000Z","SOL","Buy",7.0007542,257,36.71033043839762,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""]]},"KSM":{"Buy":[["2021-05-30T22:00:00.000Z","KSM","Buy",0.3869,100,258.46471956577926,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""]]},"ADA":{"Buy":[["2021-05-18T22:00:00.000Z","ADA","Buy",164.44,250,1.5203113597664801,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""],["2021-03-19T23:00:00.000Z","ADA","Buy",236,249.5,1.0572033898305084,"Binance","Cryptocurrency",""]]},"TSLA":{"Sell":[["2021-05-16T22:00:00.000Z","TSLA","Sell",1.8606349999999998,864,464.357598346801,"Trading212","Stock",""],["2021-01-18T23:00:00.000Z","TSLA","Sell",0.1449193,100.45,693.144391395763,"Trading212","Stock",""]],"Buy":[["2021-03-04T23:00:00.000Z","TSLA","Buy",0.3166797,150,473.6647154838153,"Trading212","Stock",""],["2021-03-02T23:00:00.000Z","TSLA","Buy",0.3841205,213.44,555.6589663920566,"Trading212","Stock",""],["2021-02-24T23:00:00.000Z","TSLA","Buy",0.3282356,188.45,574.1302893409489,"Trading212","Stock",""],["2021-02-22T23:00:00.000Z","TSLA","Buy",0.2252006,126.5,561.7214163727805,"Trading212","Stock",""],["2021-02-21T23:00:00.000Z","TSLA","Buy",0.2954647,184.99,626.0984814768059,"Trading212","Stock",""],["2021-02-21T23:00:00.000Z","TSLA","Buy",0.1624873,100,615.4327138182492,"Trading212","Stock",""],["2021-01-10T23:00:00.000Z","TSLA","Buy",0.1449193,100,690.03]
```

Produced errors

```
10:25:02 AM Info    [TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined]
10:25:02 AM Info    [TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined]
10:25:02 AM Info    [TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))]
10:25:02 AM Info    [TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined]
10:25:02 AM Info    [TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined]
10:25:02 AM Info    [TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined]
10:25:02 AM Info    [TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined]
10:25:02 AM Info    [TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined]
10:25:02 AM Info    [TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined]
10:25:02 AM Info    [TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined]
10:25:02 AM Info    [TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined]
10:25:02 AM Info    [TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))]
10:25:02 AM Info    [TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined]
10:25:02 AM Info    [TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined]
10:25:02 AM Info    [TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined]
10:25:02 AM Info    [TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined]
10:25:02 AM Info    [TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined]
10:25:02 AM Info    [TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined]
```

I am hoping someone here can help me solve this issue.

EDIT1: Adding the console.log output of `tic.Sell`

```
2:02:36 PM  Info    undefined
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Thu Oct 21 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'MATIC',
    'Sell',
    37.14,
    61.82,
    1.6645126548196014,
    'Binance',
    'Cryptocurrency',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    undefined
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Wed Oct 20 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'TFUEL',
    'Sell',
    754,
    182,
    0.2413793103448276,
    'Binance',
    'Cryptocurrency',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Wed Oct 20 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'THETA',
    'Sell',
    81.4,
    397.73,
    4.886117936117936,
    'Binance',
    'Cryptocurrency',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    undefined
2:02:36 PM  Info    undefined
2:02:36 PM  Info    undefined
2:02:36 PM  Info    undefined
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Sun Aug 08 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'safemars',
    'Sell',
    206130076,
    16,
    7.762089021885385e-8,
    'Binance',
    'Cryptocurrency',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Sun Aug 08 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'safemoon',
    'Sell',
    55800000,
    90,
    0.0000016129032258064516,
    'Binance',
    'Cryptocurrency',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Tue Jul 13 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'FRA:C36',
    'Sell',
    358,
    343.68,
    0.96,
    'Bitvavo',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Sun Jul 11 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'BTC',
    'Sell',
    0.038237,
    1116.81,
    29207.57381593744,
    'Binance',
    'Cryptocurrency',
    '' ],
  [ Sun Jul 04 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'BTC',
    'Sell',
    0.00537222,
    257,
    47838.69610700977,
    'Binance',
    'Cryptocurrency',
    '' ],
  [ Sun Jul 04 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'BTC',
    'Sell',
    0.00543778,
    261,
    47997.528403135104,
    'Binance',
    'Cryptocurrency',
    '' ],
  [ Sun Jul 04 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'BTC',
    'Sell',
    0.00533832,
    261,
    48891.78617992178,
    'Binance',
    'Cryptocurrency',
    '' ],
  [ Sun Jul 04 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'BTC',
    'Sell',
    0.00550857,
    261,
    47380.71768172139,
    'Binance',
    'Cryptocurrency',
    '' ],
  [ Sun Jul 04 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'BTC',
    'Sell',
    0.00008389000000000313,
    0,
    0,
    'Bitvavo',
    'Cryptocurrency',
    '' ],
  [ Sun Jun 06 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'BTC',
    'Sell',
    0.038276,
    1116.81,
    29177.81377364406,
    'Binance',
    'Cryptocurrency',
    '' ],
  [ Sun May 02 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'BTC',
    'Sell',
    0.01032703,
    498.75,
    48295.58934175654,
    'Bitvavo',
    'Cryptocurrency',
    '' ],
  [ Tue Apr 13 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'BTC',
    'Sell',
    0.18413661999999997,
    9757,
    52987.83044893515,
    'Bitvavo',
    'Cryptocurrency',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Fri Jul 09 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'BAT',
    'Sell',
    168.5,
    81.22,
    0.4820178041543027,
    'Binance',
    'Cryptocurrency',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Fri Jul 09 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'BNB',
    'Sell',
    0.7359,
    195.55,
    265.7290392716402,
    'Binance',
    'Cryptocurrency',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Fri Jul 09 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'LINK',
    'Sell',
    6.2,
    94.95,
    15.314516129032258,
    'Binance',
    'Cryptocurrency',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Fri Jul 09 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'XMR',
    'Sell',
    3.09982,
    681,
    219.69017555858085,
    'Binance',
    'Cryptocurrency',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    undefined
2:02:36 PM  Info    undefined
2:02:36 PM  Info    undefined
2:02:36 PM  Info    undefined
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Sun May 16 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'TSLA',
    'Sell',
    1.8606349999999998,
    864,
    464.357598346801,
    'Trading212',
    'Stock',
    '' ],
  [ Mon Jan 18 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
    'TSLA',
    'Sell',
    0.1449193,
    100.45,
    693.144391395763,
    'Trading212',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Mon Apr 12 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'MSTR',
    'Sell',
    0.61234957,
    413.5,
    675.2678866092778,
    'Trading212',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    undefined
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Sun Apr 11 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'ACTC',
    'Sell',
    8,
    109.91,
    13.73875,
    'DeGiro',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Sun Apr 11 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'CTRM',
    'Sell',
    110,
    43.46,
    0.3950909090909091,
    'DeGiro',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Sun Apr 11 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'NVCN',
    'Sell',
    74,
    61.85,
    0.8358108108108109,
    'DeGiro',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Sun Apr 11 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'SFT',
    'Sell',
    13,
    92.2,
    7.092307692307693,
    'Trading212',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    undefined
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Sun Apr 11 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'SNGX',
    'Sell',
    65,
    80.2,
    1.2338461538461538,
    'Trading212',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Sun Mar 28 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'LMND',
    'Sell',
    1.6704908,
    121.86,
    72.94862084843568,
    'Trading212',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    undefined
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Thu Mar 25 2021 19:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'AZRX',
    'Sell',
    100,
    112.35,
    1.1235,
    'Trading212',
    'Stock',
    '' ],
  [ Thu Mar 25 2021 19:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'AZRX',
    'Sell',
    59,
    66.14,
    1.1210169491525424,
    'Trading212',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    undefined
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Thu Mar 18 2021 19:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'FB',
    'Sell',
    1,
    244.81,
    244.81,
    'DeGiro',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Mon Mar 15 2021 19:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'ARB',
    'Sell',
    173.1368712,
    482.54,
    2.7870435491616994,
    'Trading212',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Wed Mar 10 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
    'GNUS',
    'Sell',
    72,
    134.94,
    1.8741666666666665,
    'Trading212',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Mon Mar 08 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
    'ABNB',
    'Sell',
    0.4281417,
    66.98,
    156.44353259680148,
    'Trading212',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Mon Mar 08 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
    'EQQQ',
    'Sell',
    1,
    253.87,
    253.87,
    'DeGiro',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    undefined
2:02:36 PM  Info    undefined
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Mon Mar 08 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
    'QDVA',
    'Sell',
    6,
    48.93,
    8.155,
    'DeGiro',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Mon Mar 08 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
    'SPY',
    'Sell',
    5,
    273.66,
    54.732000000000006,
    'DeGiro',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Mon Mar 08 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
    'SXLV',
    'Sell',
    7,
    188.23,
    26.889999999999997,
    'DeGiro',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Sun Mar 07 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
    'BABA',
    'Sell',
    1.7718482,
    342.51,
    193.3066275090609,
    'Trading212',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Sun Mar 07 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
    'NIO',
    'Sell',
    1.888702,
    61.79,
    32.71558986012616,
    'Trading212',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Wed Feb 24 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
    'IQQH',
    'Sell',
    5,
    60.09,
    12.018,
    'DeGiro',
    'Stock',
    '' ],
  [ Wed Feb 24 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
    'IQQH',
    'Sell',
    2,
    25.63,
    12.815,
    'DeGiro',
    'Stock',
    '' ],
  [ Wed Feb 24 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
    'IQQH',
    'Sell',
    8,
    102.46,
    12.8075,
    'DeGiro',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Mon Feb 22 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
    'ESPO',
    'Sell',
    5,
    191.18,
    38.236000000000004,
    'Trading212',
    'Stock',
    '' ],
  [ Mon Feb 22 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
    'ESPO',
    'Sell',
    4.994859,
    186.59,
    37.35640986061869,
    'Trading212',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Sun Feb 21 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
    'AMZN',
    'Sell',
    0.05568394,
    147.39,
    2646.903218414501,
    'Trading212',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Sun Feb 21 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
    'COUP',
    'Sell',
    0.5194278,
    155.58,
    299.521896979715,
    'Trading212',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Sun Feb 21 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
    'CRWD',
    'Sell',
    0.5152084,
    99.28,
    192.69872152705585,
    'Trading212',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Sun Feb 21 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
    'FVRR',
    'Sell',
    0.5002109,
    122.67,
    245.2365592193213,
    'Trading212',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Sun Feb 21 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
    'TTWO',
    'Sell',
    1,
    160.04,
    160.04,
    'Trading212',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Wed Jan 27 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
    'NAKD',
    'Sell',
    55.421,
    68.03,
    1.2275130365745837,
    'Trading212',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Mon Dec 07 2020 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
    'OTGLY',
    'Sell',
    6.180493,
    91.07,
    14.735070487095445,
    'Trading212',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Sun Nov 29 2020 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
    'WDI',
    'Sell',
    23,
    8.21,
    0.35695652173913045,
    'DeGiro',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Tue Sep 08 2020 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'ADP',
    'Sell',
    1,
    114.63,
    114.63,
    'DeGiro',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Tue Sep 08 2020 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'AQN',
    'Sell',
    3,
    35.2,
    11.733333333333334,
    'DeGiro',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
2:02:36 PM  Info    [ [ Tue Sep 08 2020 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    'MGRC',
    'Sell',
    1,
    53.1,
    53.1,
    'DeGiro',
    'Stock',
    '' ] ]
```

Comment: Are you getting the error at this `Object.keys(securityObject).forEach` line or this other one `tic.Sell.forEach`?

Comment: @ale13 the error is in `tic.Sell.forEach`

Comment: And how does the `tic.Sell` look like?

Comment: I will edit the question and add the output. Interestingly, THETA seems to be present in the `tic.Sell`

Comment: @ale13 someone suggested it might be a decimal problem. I added `totalBuy.toFixed(8); total.toFixed(8);  quanity.toFixed(8); remainder.toFixed(8)` and it seemed to have fixed part of the issue, for example MSTR is now present in report tab. However, THETA is still not and I still receive same errors.

Comment: @YuriKhristich You were such a great help the last time, would you like to share your view on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem exists inside the do/while loop.
`Remainder` becomes incredibly small (for MSTR, remainder = 5.551115123125783e-17 instead of 0) but not quite zero, so the loop runs again and an error is thrown. `MSTR` and `THETA` are thus never pushed into `objects`.

Fixed the issue by changing `while (remainder > 1e-9)`. Might not be the best fix but it works.